# How to make configslurper delegate method call to caller class

Tags: groovy

I want to create a groovy class og script like this:

```
//...
def slurper = new ConfigSlurper().parse(someFile)
//...
//The exact method declaration
def methodCall(def arg){
   //Whatever i want to do
}
//Maybe it is easier with methodMissing
def methodMissing(def args) {
   //Whatever i want to do
}
```

The file to slurp could look like this:

```
some {
   property = methodCall("with arg")
}
```

The question is how i can delegate the "methodCall" to the class or script that parses with the configslurper? At the moment it will give you a methodMissing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sérgio Michels link I found a solution:

```
public class ScriptWithMethods extends Script {

   String scriptText;

   public ScriptWithMethods(File file) {
      scriptText = file.text
   }

   public void run() {
      GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
      Closure closure = shell.evaluate("{it->$string}");
      closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
      closure.delegate = this
      closure.call()
   }

   def methodCall(def arg){
      //Whatever i want to do
   }
}

//...
def script = new ScriptWithMethods(scriptText:someFile)
def slurper = new ConfigSlurper().parse(script)
```

Of cause you could also use "method missing", but this works in my usecase

Answer (score 2):

I thik that [this blog post](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/07/30/modularizing-groovy-config-files-with-a-dash-of-meta-programming/) have an example of what are you trying to do. It's more complicated than a `methodMissing` but can be done.

Comment: Thank you. I actually found that post some time ago, but never got to read it. It pointed me in the right direction, but I will post an answer myself for the next reader.